# How to Pass Complex Array in Retrofit 2 using URL encoding

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

**This is My Code in Calling Activity**

```
APIInterface apiService = RestClient.getApiService();

Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.saveFeedback(mAuthToken, myObjcetArrayList;
```

And This is my Interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("training/feedback/save")
Call<JsonObject> saveFeedback(@Header("X-Auth-Token") String Authorization, ArrayList<FeedbackData> jsonObject);
```

Comment: Please show the error you get and a [mcve] of the code

Comment: For starters, `myObjcetArrayList;` doesn't compile without a closing bracket . Secondly, you're posting JSON data... Not clear what the server is expecting

Comment: [{"key":"feedbackId","value":"1","description":""},{"key":"feedbackForm[0].questionId","value":"2","description":""},{"key":"feedbackForm[0].value","value":"5","description":""},{"key":"feedbackForm[1].questionId","value":"3","description":""},{"key":"feedbackForm[1].value","value":"4","description":""}]

Comment: server want like that data

Comment: That's definitely JSON, not URL encoded